# How to schedule jenkins to start every day between 6PM to 7AM and on frieday and saterday run every 30 minutes

Tags: jenkins, cron

I am trying to schedule a jenkins build with the following: 
start every day between 6PM to 7AM and on Friday and Saturday run every 30 minutes... but it seems for some reason a little bit hard. 
Any help will be appreciates.

Comment: You have to configure two builds. one for friday and saturday and on for the rest

Comment: Good idea. Thought I could do it in one line somehow...

Answer (score 0):

So I used 2 different jobs:

first is:

- H/30 * *  * 5-6 - every hour at weekend (Friday and Saturday)
- H/60 18,7 * * 0-5 - Every hour between 18:00 to 7:00 on working days

Comment: You don't need two jobs for this; you just need to put those two separate cron expressions, each on their own line, into the "Build periodically" field.

Comment: Also, your second expression doesn't do what you expect: it will run on Sundays (in addition to Mon-Fri), and only twice — once between 07:00 and 07:59, and once between 18:00 and 18:59.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the second expression as for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by checking "Build periodically" and entering the following:

```
# Run every thirty minutes for the 48 hours of Friday and Saturday
H/30 * * * 5-6

# Run once per hour, between 18:00 and 06:59, on Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri
H 18-6 * * 1-5
```

Note also that this second expression will not run from Friday 6pm until Saturday 7am — it will stop at midnight, and resume again on Monday morning between midnight and 7am.